# How to map a hibernate query to a custom class in a JpaRepository

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I believe that it is possible to map a hibernate query to a custom class. This has been described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-query-to-custom-class)

```
Query<Result> query = session.createQuery("select new com.baeldung.hibernate.pojo.Result(m.name, m.department.name)"
  + " from com.baeldung.hibernate.entities.DeptEmployee m");
```

my question is can I use the `new` keyword in the `@Query` of a JPA respository. For example,

```
public interface PersonRepo extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {

@Query("SELECT distinct p FROM Person p  "
List<Person> getPersons(Instant lastProcessedTime);
```

Comment: Yes, you can use,  did you try ?

Comment: Thanks. You inspired me to give it a go and it does appear to just work. thanks. Sorry I should have tried first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you can do it as shown below:

```
    @Repository
    public interface PersonRepo extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {

    @Query("select new domain.PersonDto(p.personId,p.storedFrom) from"
            + " domain.Person p")
    List<PersonDto> getModifiedPersons();
```